# Replace markdown bold syntax with latex code

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am struggling to construct the correct regex expression to replace markdown bold syntax (double stars) with LaTeX code using the `stringr::str_replace_all()` function.

For example, I have the string `"**first chunk** not bold, and **bold again**"`, and I would like to convert it to `"\textbf{first chunk} not bold, and \textbf{bold again}"`.

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(
  "**first chunk** not bold, and **bold again**",
  pattern = "\\*\\*.*\\*\\*", # this probably needs to be updated 
  replacement = <what goes here?>
)
#> "\textbf{first chunk} not bold, and \textbf{bold again}"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capture groups:

```r
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(
  "**first chunk** not bold, and **bold again**",
  pattern = "\\*\\*(.*?)\\*\\*",
  replacement = "\\\\textbf{\\1}"
)

[1] "\\textbf{first chunk} not bold, and \\textbf{bold again}"
```